Is a constant function an exception to the rule "The derivative of an Even function is always Odd"
I was studying about Even and Odd functions and I came across a statement
"The derivative of an Even function is always Odd"
and instead of taking it by word I wanted to verify it so I took some functions where I noticed that a constant function's derivative is even and odd.
I am confused whether the derivative also being Odd matters and does the rule still hold.
$f(x) = 6$ is an even function.
$f^{'}(x) = 0$ it is even and odd.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Quick tip (for your next question). If I can't work out what the question is from the question itself (and have to re-read the heading), I'm probably going to move on to the next question in the list and ignore yours.  Which is a pity, because this is quite a nice question (with an excellent answer already provided).

I guess that the statements of calculus that you have in mind are

If $f(x)$ is even, then its derivative $f'(x)$ is odd.
If $f(x)$ is odd, then its derivative $f'(x)$ is even.

As you say, considering the even function $f(x)\equiv 6$ and taking its derivative, you obtain the odd function $f(x)\equiv 0$. This last function is odd, so the theorem works and nothing fails. The fact that the null function is also even is just because this is a special case.
Note that the null function is the only odd and even function, and those statements are just implications and not equivalences. Your post is exactly one counterexample for this.
